# Querying array from Firebase (React Native)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to react-native and firebase, and I am building an app. I stumble upon a problem using "array" in firebase (i know that firebase doesn't work with array), but I want to know if there is some way to retrieve this data.

This is the data I have in the server, and I want to get all the purchases that have the product "id" (in red)

[image]

I tried to use the code below and some variants but no success, returns null

```
firebase.database().ref('purchases').orderByChild("products/id")
.equalTo("-Lgida0VKuZZ6V7K0LkH").on('value', function (rawPurchases)
```

I want to know if there is a way to get this information.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text or code.  Copy the code directly into the question and format it as code.

Comment: Your current data model makes it easy to find all the products in a purchase. It does not make it easy to find all the purchases that have a specific product. You'll want to store a so-called reverse index to allow that use case, with a top-level node `product_purchases`, under which you have each product, and then under there, all the purchases that contain that product. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Answer (score 0):

```
var scoresRef = firebase.database().ref("purchases");
scoresRef.orderByChild("products").on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log("The " + data.id + " data is " + data.val());
  });
});
```

try this method and review more [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/database/reference/Query.md)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i need something that the server will do the job, not the client. As you showed i will get all purchases and then filter on the client